# Как можно непрерывно отслеживать в EditText ввод текста?

Tags: android

К примеру, чтобы каждый введенный символ обрабатывался.

В Edittext назначил onClick, он работает только при первом наведении курсора на этот EditText и когда нажимают Enter.

Как еще можно?

Comment: @metalurgus я там искал, не нашел, потому как не знал, как это искать и какие слова писать, потому и обратился сюда

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почитайте на досуге

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#onTextChanged(java.lang.CharSequence, int, int, int)

Comment: @Чад, спасибо боьшое